# Receiving data in php server from form using $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Getting following error in place of the value

> Notice: Undefined index: data in /home/ashutosh/public_html/xyz/about/testimonials/serviceTestimonials.php on line 6
>   dddd

## The code segment:

On webpage:
.
.
.

```
               <form id="formTesti" name="formTesti" action="serviceTestimonial.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name ="row" id="row" value="10">
                    <button type="submit" name="button" id="buttonPrev" value="Prev">Previous</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="button" id="buttonNext" value="Next">Next</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        //get the data when loading the page
        $(document).ready(
                function()
                {
                    $("#formTesti").submit(function(){
                        return false;
                        //event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    $("#buttonPrev").click(function(){
                        $("#page").val(parseInt($("#page").val())-1);
                        Doit();
                    });

                    $("#buttonNext").click(function(){
                        $("#page").val(parseInt($("#page").val())+1);
                        Doit();
                    });

                    function Doit(){
                        var data = $("#formTesti:input").serializeArray();
                        //alert(data);
                        $.post(
                                "serviceTestimonials.php",
                                data,
                                function(json){
                                    if(json.status="fail")
                                        alert(json.message());
                                    else {

                                    }
                                },
                                "json"
                        );
                    }
                }
        );

    </script>
```

---

server side code:

```
print_r($_POST["data"]);

die(" dddd ");
```

---

Comment: are you getting your form values did you alert the data before sending to server..

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST)` to see what is being passsed if anything

Comment: Dear Choco, how to check the serialized data at java side? Alert is not working.

Comment: Dear B-and-P, i tried print_r($_POST["data"]); and that is giving error... :(

Comment: ashutosh you just cant say that you are getting the error. You have to tell which error,

Comment: Dear Arif, the error as mentioned in question is "Undefined index" error.

Comment: ashutosh, Thats means you dont have any thing in  `['data']` just try this `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: I am getting the error from print_r

Comment: Arif you are right I tried without data. Now could you please let me know why the data is not going? I am following very basic textbook code here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for support. It seems when $.post is used for json data transfer, we need to use the parameter in callback function for client to server data transfer as well as server to client.

So code changes required was:
var **json** = $("#formTesti:input").serializeArray();

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass key value pair for data in post.. not data variable.. something like this

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Comment: Dear Vineet, I am creating the dataarray using serializeArray on form element.

Comment: data is the java variable which is loaded with form data using 
var data = $("#formTesti:input").serializeArray();

Comment: data is javascript variable.. try print_r($_POST).. Try with $_POST['page'] and $_POST['row']

Comment: I had to initialize the parameter in callback function. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $("#formTesti").serialize();
$.post(
    "serviceTestimonials.php",
    data: data,
    function(json){
      if(json.status="fail")
          alert(json.message());
      else {

      }
   },
"json"
);
```

Comment: Dear Melisozmen, .serialize creates xml output whereas i am interested in Json so used serializeArray. Error is that we need to populate variable passed to callback function, in this case is named json.